# MySQL many to many vs json

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I am trying to define some MySQL relations. I have 3 tables as given below:

```
     employee:
     | id | first_name | last_name | email

     notifications: (notification names are email, post etc)
     | id | name             | description

     employee_notifications:
     | id | employee_id | notification_id |
```

Is there any advantage (or disadvantage) in changing the employee_notifications table to insert all notification ids of an employee in one row using json_encode?

As of now, there are like 100 employees and 6 notification methods.

Comment: Suggest removing the mysql tag, and the php tag.  This is a general relational database design question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any advantage (or disadvantage) in changing the employee_notifications table to insert all notification ids of an employee in one row using json_encode?

There are significant disadvantages. With your current setup, you can easily find out which notifications an employee has, or which employees subscribe to a particular notification. Putting it as JSON in the employees table is going to remove your ability to do that.

Comment: What about fulltext search on the JSON?

Comment: @JanDvorak Not very efficient, prone to oopses (searching for ID "123" may find "1234"), etc.

Comment: And also can't search for stop words, or for non-words, or for short words. Full-text search is not designed for reading code. Also, lack of structure - if you want to search for an email with a particular description, you could find that description with a post, for a user that also has an unrelated email attached.

Comment: You are right. I do have some reports to run and I am aware that fulltext search won't work. Looks like I have to go back to the good old db design classes!! I was trying to choose between a (json_decode + array process) vs the classic many-to-many db design for report generation

Answer (score 1):

While not always a perfect approach, nor applicable in all situations, a good rule of thumb for good maintainability over time:

Use well normalized (I won't say fully, because sometimes that is going too far) in your primary data structures, and  uses views, stored procedures, or code synthesized data objects to create optimized usage views of that data.